# Maintaining the CheckBox Behaviour

Tags: android, checkbox

I am having a select all checkbox button in my layout and a list view each with a check box in the right. I have added following code for the select all checkbox as :

selectall.setOnCheckChangedListener code :-

```
for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
    RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox);
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

Here I am maintaining each list view item

```
holder.mcbGoupMember.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    commonFriends.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
                }
            });
```

Now here I am stuck in a situation, I want that when I manually select all the checkbox items, then at that instant the select all button/checkbox should automatically be checked on and vice versa.

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample program for [**listview checkbox scroll issue**](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a simple count of the number of items you have checked at a time. If you check an item increase it by one, if you uncheck an item decrease it by one. After each increase/decrease check if this checked items number is equal to number of items on your list and check the select all if it is. Just make sure that your `selectall.setOnCheckChangedListener` sets the list checkbox values to whatever value it receives in `isChecked`. For example:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
  for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
      RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox);
      cb.setChecked(isChecked);
  }
}
```